# Jquery IF hover (execute) ELSE fadein/out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an IF statement to my script. Originally my script is supposed to fade out when there is no mouse movement & fade back in when there is. I'm trying to make it so that it stays faded in regardless of mouse movement if I hover over the DIV running the script.

http://jsfiddle.net/2kyaJ/1098/

```
$(function () {
    var timer;
    var fadeInBuffer = false;



    $(document).mousemove(function () {
        if (('.fade-object').mouseover) {
            $('.fade-object').fadeIn();

        } else {

        if (!fadeInBuffer) {
            if (timer) {
                console.log("clearTimer");
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = 0;
            }

                console.log("fadeIn");
            $('.fade-object').fadeIn();
            $('html').css({
                cursor: ''
            });
        } else {
            fadeInBuffer = false;
        }


        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("fadeout");
            $('.fade-object').fadeOut()
            $('html').css({
                cursor: 'none'
            });
            fadeInBuffer = true;
        }, 1000)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouvemove` helps?

Comment: That's for the DIV only, though? If the mouse moves anywhere on the screen it needs to fade in & back out after a set time. Hovering specifically over the DIV is when it stays faded in. Basically I'm trying to get what you see on Bing.com

Answer (score 0):

This is not the whole solution, but may help.

Set `var` that tells you if `div` is hovered or not:

```
var hovered = false;
$('div').on('mouseenter', function () {
    hovered = true;
});
$('div').on('mouseleave', function () {
    hovered = false;
});
```

Turn on and off `mousemove` event:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function () {...});
$(document).off('mousemove', function () {...});
```

So you can for example switching `mousemove` event when hovering/leaving the `div` or you can check `if (hovered == true) {...}`. The choice is yours :)

Comment: So I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/k1rbrxp1/ but nothing happens, it shows both the class & id with no fading at all.